# Regular expression for date validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a problem in validating the date, In my code I have used a regular expression which accepts dates of year 2012, if I give date having yr as 2013 it says "Invalid date". Kindly help me on this regard. It should accept any years.. I mean valid years atleast from year 2000 to year 3000. 
Thanks in advance.

```
function checkDates(){
  var sdate = "2013-01-02";
  var edate = "2013-01-02";

  if (!isValidDate(sdate)) {
         alert("Report Start Date is Invalid!!");
         return false;
    } 

    if (!isValidDate(edate)) {
     alert("Report End Date is Invalid!!");
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}


function isValidDate(sText) {

    var reDate = /(?:([0-9]{4}) [ -](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ -]0[1-9]|1[012])/;  // yy/mm/dd
    return reDate.test(sText);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it close to impossible to validate dates properly with a regular expression? How can you decide whether February has 28 or 29 days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an extra space in your regex and missing brackets (bracket issue makes it accept `2012-aa-xx` date:

```
/(?:([0-9]{4}) [ -](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ -]0[1-9]|1[012])/
              ^                               ^
-------------/-------------------------------/
```

So:

```
([0-9]{4}[ -](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ -](0[1-9]|1[012]))
```

Comment: Yes,.. Brackets makes issues.. thanks for correcting me. The expression works!!! @oleq: thanks

Answer (score 1):

the below expression also works

```
/(?:19|20\d{2})\-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/
```

Thanks,
Dhiraj